# Can't change text in ViewHolder item from another adapter

Tags: android, android-viewholder

I have 2 RecyclerViews(Content, Header), and when i click on Button in ContentRecyclerView View i need to change text in HeaderRecyclerView TextView.  How can i make it? 
I use thi method

Content Adapter

```
OnClick{
...
 HeaderDistrRecycleAdapter.sendChangedField(keyNumber);
...
}
```

in Header Adapter

```
public static void sendChangedField(int keyNumber) {
        String s = String.valueOf(setTotalSkuValue(Queries.getCountSKU(String.valueOf(keyNumber)), keyNumber)); // here i have required String with correct value
        holder.skus[keyNumber - 9].setText(s); //array of TextViews
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added to OnClick

```
((PageDistrRecycleList) context).notifyChangeField();
```

and

```
 headerAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0);
```

to PageDistrRecycleList, and it works.